# RegEx to close an unclosed tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have received some invalid XML data from a poll provider and would like to clean up several unclosed tags before processing.

The data currently looks like this:

```
<questions>
<question number="1">
<title>What is your name?</title>
<answer>John Doe<answer> <!-- this is the problem -->
</question>
<question number="2">
...
</question>
```

Is there a way with regular expressions to clean this and go ahead and close that `<answer>` tag?

I have this: `"<answer>.*?(?<closingtag><answer>)"` to find the occurrences, but how do I do a specific replacement on that `<closingtag>` named group?

Sorry for this very basic question, but I am struggling a bit with my regex expression.

Thanks,

Hal

Comment: This poll provider provides bad XML for a living? Do them a favor and tell them they have a bug and that they must fix it (preferably before they are paid for spewing garbage).

Comment: Also, FYI, in general, regular expressions can't be used to process XML, as XML is not a regular language (in cs terms).

Comment: Thanks - the more I look at this, the worse the idea seems (using regex to fix). As for the poll provider, it's PollDaddy, but they made a custom change quickly for us and introduced the bug. Normally, it's dead on. They were quick to fix the problem, we just have a significant number that got into our queue.

Comment: Please consider fixing the XML by passing it through tidy, instead of rolling your own routine.

Comment: Just wonder if the <answer> tags you have to close appear repetitively -- if not, you can just do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatic repair of human error in XML validation is asking for trouble.  In the extreme, you might as well undo all XML validation.  Take just one example:

```
<questions> 
<question number="1"> 
<title>What is your name?</title> 
<answer>John Doe<answer> 
<!-- this is the problem --> </question> <question number="2"> ... </question>
```

Repair...

```
<answer>John Doe</answer>
```

Or...

```
<answer>John</answer><answer> Doe</answer>
```

Or...

```
<answer>John Doe</answer><answer> </answer>
```

Can you see where this is headed?

Comment: I ended up simply handling the specific problem in the documents that contained the error.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is always a missing / (that is, there *is* a matching tag, but it's not currently a *closing* one), you could do something like this:

Find: `<([^/>]+)>([^<]*?)<\1>`

Replace with: `<\1>\2</\1>`

This would attempt to find tags that are two-in-a-row-unclosed tags (not including self-closing tags), and replace them with the tag, the content, and then a closing version of the tag.

There are some caveats, of course - if a tag has an attribute that includes a `/`, or if the value of the unclosed tag includes `<` (or other tags) this regex wouldn't work.

Comment: Um… no. `<bla>asda</bla><bla>` (i.e.: Please do not recommend regex as a tool to fix XML. It won't work. It never does.)

Comment: Modified to more restrictive regex. In limited situations, it *can* work. It all depends on how general your problem is. "Fixing XML" in a general sense is a much more complicated problem, which regex isn't generally suited for, yes. But sometimes problems aren't as complicated as the general case.

Comment: +1. Looks good now.  (Except `\1`, `\2` in the replacement string should be `$1`, `$2`.)

Comment: Sure, until the simple test case you started with and works so well introduces a bug 3 months down the road that is next to impossible to track down because there's no exceptions.  User's don't understand the words "system limitation".

Answer (score 0):

For this case (a Vim regex), when all tags to treat are a simple code line:

```
:%s/\(<.\{-}>.\{-}<\(\/\)\@!\)/\1\//g
```

`\(\/\)\@!` assures match only unclosed `<...>` tag